# Blueimp Gallery : External link on carousel images

Tags: javascript, carousel, blueimp

I've set up a carousel with Blueimp Gallery plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery), it's working but when i click on a image, i want to disable the controls toggle and instead have the default link behaviour to another page of the website.

I need the indicators to be always visible.
Is it possible to use "a" tag's href value to go to another page ?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="images-slider">
    <a href="http://www.google.fr" data-link="http://lorempixel.com/878/330/nature/9/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/878/330/nature/9/" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.fr" data-link="http://lorempixel.com/878/330/nature/4/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/878/330/nature/4/" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.fr" data-link="http://lorempixel.com/878/330/nature/5/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/878/330/nature/5/" alt="">
    </a> 
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('images-slider').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#slider',
        carousel: true,
        thumbnailIndicators: false,
        urlProperty: 'link'
    }
);
```

here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0hb7gdeq/1/

thx

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is optimal in any way but i got it to work by wrapping another  tag around the innerHTML like this.

```
blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('images-slider').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
    container: '#slider',
    carousel: true,
    thumbnailIndicators: false,
    urlProperty: 'link',
    onslidecomplete: function (index, slide) {
        var href = this.list[index].getAttribute('href');
        slide.innerHTML = "<a href='"+href+"'>" + slide.innerHTML + "</a>";
    }
);
```

The css also needs a tweak after this hack

```
.blueimp-gallery>.slides .slide .slide-content {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, mate!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks oBo, I extended your code to also work with the title attribute, which I needed on my slides, with some jQuery to find the title attribute.

```
var title;
// [...]

onslidecomplete: function(index, slide) {
                        title = $(slide).find("img").attr("title");
                        var href = this.list[index].getAttribute('href');
                        slide.innerHTML = "<a href='" + href + "' title='"+title+"'>" + slide.innerHTML + "</a>";
                    }
```

**Full Code:**

**HTML**

```
<!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
        <div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel-home" class="my-blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel blueimp-gallery-controls">
            <div class="slides"></div>
            <div class="menu-tile-text">
                <h4 class="title"></h4>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <a class="play-pause"></a>
            <ol style="bottom: 12px;" class="indicator"></ol>
        </div>

        <div id="links-home" style="display:none;">
            <a href="#/somesite" data-link="assets/img/640x360.jpg" title="banana">
                <img src="assets/img/640x360.jpg" alt="banana">
            </a>
            <a href="#/site" data-link="assets/img/640x360.jpg" title="banana">
                <img src="assets/img/640x360.jpg" alt="banana">
            </a>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //BlueImp Carousel
        document.getElementById('links-home').onclick = function(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
                link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
                options = {
                    index: link,
                    event: event
                },
                links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
            blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
        };

        var title;
        blueimp.Gallery(
            document.getElementById('links-home').getElementsByTagName('a'), {
                container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel-home',
                carousel: true,
                thumbnailIndicators: false,
                transitionSpeed: 400,
                slideshowInterval: 8000,
                clearSlides: true,
                titleElement: 'h4',
                urlProperty: 'link',
                onslidecomplete: function(index, slide) {
                    title = $(slide).find("img").attr("title");
                    var href = this.list[index].getAttribute('href');
                    slide.innerHTML = "<a href='" + href + "' title='" + title + "'>" + slide.innerHTML + "</a>";
                }

            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: As you have implemented it a few days ago, maybe you can help me as I can't make it work. I have my `<div id="links">`, so I have set `document.getElementById('links')` but then I don't know what is `container: '#slider'`, should it be `blueimp-gallery-carousel` in place of `slider` ? But even with this, when I click it doesn't open the picture...

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have access to my implementation, as it was a kind of secret work project. I suggest you inspect the elements (F12) and see where your image hrefs go.

Comment: Ok. That's the thing I can't see them added, but I'll conitnue to search. Thanks

Comment: Got access to my code again! I just added my full implementation, hope it helps!

Comment: Great ! I could have make working your example ! I'll work on it to achieve what I need ! Thanks !

Comment: So I made it work ! i.e. http://edlo.eu/en/ad/demonstration-ad/hrt7ys. Thanks !!!

Comment: Awesome! But look beneath your footer, maybe add `#links{display:none}`

Comment: Oups... ;-) Thanks for the notice !

Comment: For people trying to have quick pages and avoiding JQuery you can get the title like this: var title = slide.children[0].getAttribute('title');